# How to import an object and run a function for all properties in module?

Tags: node.js

I created a module to store an object with some properties containing array of strings. Once it is imported, I want to get a sample of this array (eg: using [lodash / sample](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sample)). So I do not have to use the 'sample' method every time the module is imported and a property is referenced. Obs.: I want to reference an object and a property, not a function.

/store.js

```
export default {
  foo: [
    `This is the first message`,
    `This is the second message`,
    `This is the third message`
  ],
  bar: [
    `This is the message one`,
    `This is the message two`,
    `This is the message three`
  ]
};
```

I want to avoid this:

/file.js

```
import store from './store';
import sample from 'lodash/sample';

const msg = sample(store.foo);
console.log(msg); // e.g: This is the second message
```

and use something like this:

/file.js

```
import store from './store';

const msg = store.foo;
console.log(msg); // e.g: This is the first message
```

Comment: Just export a function that samples from the array? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is there a way to do this referencing a property?